# Generate multiple files from a single stream. Gulp

Tags: javascript, stream, gulp

I use `for`, but this is not right.

```
gulp.task('themes', function() {
    for (var color in config.themes) {
        for (var shine in config.shines) {
            gulp.src(['src/scss/_config.scss'])
                .pipe(rename('_' + config.themes[color] + '-' + config.shines[shine] + '.scss'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scss/themes'));
        }
    }
});
```

How could I do with streams?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use multiple pipe gulp.dest() functions:

```
gulp.task('themes', function() {
   for (var color in config.themes) {
        for (var shine in config.shines) {
            gulp.src(['src/scss/_config.scss'])
                .pipe(rename('_' + config.themes[color] + '-' + config.shines[shine] + '.scss'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scss/themes'));
                .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scss/themes2'));
        }
    }
});'src/scss/themes'));
```